# how to set gbak in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, firebird

I have an API that needs gbak to work cause of this call:

```
String command = "gbak -b -v -g -user " + username + " -password " + password + " " + databasePath + " " + backupPathUpdated;

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();

process.waitFor();
```

I created a dockerfile like this:

```
# Use an official OpenJDK runtime as a parent image
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Run application when the container launches
CMD ["java", "-jar", "target/poc-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

When I tried to run the image, I faced this error:

```
Java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gbak": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1142)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.BackupSchedulerService.getBackup(BackupSchedulerService.java:52)
    at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.BackupSchedulerService.lambda$executeBackup$0(BackupSchedulerService.java:35)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1109)
    ... 4 more
```

I tried to change my dockerfile to this:

```
# Use an official OpenJDK runtime as a parent image
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install gbak
RUN apk --no-cache add firebird

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Run application when the container launches
CMD ["java", "-jar", "target/poc-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

but then I can't create a image, this is the error:

```
 => ERROR [3/4] RUN apk --no-cache add firebird                                                                                                          1.3s 
   8 | >>> RUN apk --no-cache add firebird
   9 |
  10 |     # Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
--------------------
```

How can I solve my problem?

I tried to change dockerfile, to have gbak dependency, but I had another error.

UPDATE:

I could solve using this in my dockerfile:

RUN apk --no-cache add wget tar procps xz make build-base 
&& wget https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/releases/download/v4.0.4/Firebird-4.0.4.3010-0.i686.tar.gz 
&& tar -xzf Firebird-4.0.4.3010-0.i686.tar.gz 
&& cd Firebird-4.0.4.3010-0.i686 
&& ls -l 
&& wget https://github.com/libtom/libtommath/releases/download/v1.2.0/ltm-1.2.0.tar.xz 
&& tar -xJf ltm-1.2.0.tar.xz 
&& cd libtommath-1.2.0 
&& make 
&& make install 
&& cd ../ 
&& apk del wget tar xz make build-base 
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* /app

Comment: What has the question to do with Java? You are having an issue with Firebird installation.

Comment: Why can't you use Jaybird's [gbak service support](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#services-backup-and-restore) to perform the backup? (Jaybird is the Firebird JDBC driver and contains additional features to access services like backup and restore.)

Comment: As an aside, creating a string to only then split it again doesn't make a lot of sense to me, why not just create an array with the individual arguments.

Comment: BTW: Do you really want your application and Firebird in the same Docker image?

Comment: Thank you very much! @MarkRotteveel, this link helped me a lot! I made a lot of changes to my code after reading it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the package firebird is not available in the Alpine package repositories. I would suggest trying to manually download and install the Firebird database server tools in your dockerfile, something similar to this:

```
# firebird download and install
RUN wget https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/releases/download/R3_0_9/Firebird-3.0.9.53074-0.amd64.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf Firebird-3.0.9.53074-0.amd64.tar.gz \
    && cd Firebird-3.0.9.53074-0.amd64 \
    && ./install.sh -silent
```

Consider that I fabricated the GitHub link, you will need to change it based on your requirements. Let me know if manually installing it solves your issues.

Comment: also, check this:
https://gist.github.com/usmansaleem/1cb81d366fd721bd09b85579dc37aacf
it may be useful